# google maps api http error

Tags: python, api, google-maps

I am trying to learn running googlemaps api on python using the windows powershell

## import statements

```
import googlemaps
from googlemaps import Client

mapService = Client(you_key,your_client_id,your_client_secret)
directions = mapService.directions('Texarkana','Atlanta')

for step in directions['Directions']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:
        print (step['descriptionHtml'])
```

This is the code i am using and i have the api key, client id and secret from google developer console

I have been getting the error

> googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError:HTTPError:403

Its not the 403 forbidden error and not something that i was able to find out.
Kindly someone help me out. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may use the `{}` button in the editor to format a code block. Please inspect the preview of your post beforehand

Comment: What Google Maps API are you using? But base on the documents that I found, error:403 means [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/errors). "Your API key is not valid or was not included in the request. Please ensure that you've included the entire key, and that you've enabled the API for this key."